# Determining if two sets are equal, subsets of one another, or neither

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

**Problems:**

1.) $A = \{x \mid x^4 - 3x^2 = 4\}$, $B = \{x \mid x^2 - 4 = 0\}$

2.) $A = \{x \in \mathbb{C} \mid x^3 = 1\}$, $B = \{x \in \mathbb{C} \mid x^2 + x +1 = 0\}$

3.)

$A$ = The (**real**) domain of the function f(x) = $Ln|x|$

$B$ = The (**real**) domain of the function f(x) = $1/x$

**Attempt**

1.)

The first one is fairly straightforward.

If you simply solve for $B$, You will find that there are two solutions that makes the equation true.

**x =$\pm$2**

If you simply solve for $A$, You will find that there are four solutions that makes the equation true.

**x =$\pm$2**  and  **x =$\pm\sqrt7$**

**Thus $B$ is a proper subset of $A$**

**2.)**

the second is still fairly straightforward.

Now that the domain of $x$ is of complex numbers, we have to be on the look out for real numbers and imaginary numbers since they are what makes a complex number.

For set $A$, The only solution that makes this equation true is 1. So the only elements that is in set $A$ is 1

Upon further examination of set $B$, you will come to find out that you can't factor this quadratic equation through normal means nor can you rewrite it using $i$(An example of what I mean: $x^2 + 4 = 0$ can be rewritten as $x^2 - 4i^2 = 0$). So the only thing we can do is use the quadratic equation.

The result that I got from using the quadratic equation:

$(-1\pm i\sqrt3)/2$

**From the looks of it, neither set $A$ and set $B$ are equal.**

**3.)**

I'm stuck on this question and I don't know who to go about starting this problem.

**Is all of work from problem 1 and 2 correct?**

Comment: For $(2)$ there are three solutions for $A$ in the complex numbers.

Comment: (2) is wrong. Note that $x^3-1 = (x^2+x+1)(x-1)$  
For (3) do you mean you can't even begin to figure out what _one_ of the sets is?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Well mostly how to prove that these two sets are equal or vice versa.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Now I see what I did wrong in part 2. I will fix it now

Comment: @Deathslice: The _first_ part of that is to figure out what the sets _are_. Start by doing that and worry about whether they are the same later.

Comment: @HenningMakholm for which part?

Comment: @HenningMakholm What you do mean by the number -42? All I've presented for part 3 are two functions whose domains are of the real numbers and In my attempt, I didn't show any work for part 3. So where are you getting the number -42 from?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oh I'm sorry. Sorry if I worded it wrong because I knew negative were included. I should have said all real numbers except zero.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes I can see that clearly. I will be deleting that comment since it serves no purpose and is mostly a distraction.

Comment: @HenningMakholm After analyzing my solution from part 1, I realized that the sqrt of 7 does not equal what's on the right side of the equation which means I must discard that solution. Are there imaginary numbers involved in that equation as well? Can you work it out and see where I went wrong?

Comment: @Deathslice: I can't even see your work, but the roots ought to be $\pm2$ and $\pm i$. The notation $\{x\mid \cdots\}$ doesn't really make clear whether complex roots are supposed to be part of the set or not.

Comment: @HenningMakholm That kinda throw me off first because the problem didn't state what domain x was in. Anyways I just wanted to inform you of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part $1)$ is correct. Part $2)$, though, isn't:

The equation $x^3 = 1$ has three complex solutions (including $1$). In general, any polynomial of degree $n$ has exactly $n$ complex roots (Fundamental Theorem of Algebra).

The solutions to $x^3 = 1$ are:

$$x_1 = e^{i 2 \pi /3}, x_2 = e^{-i 2 \pi /3}, x_3 = 1$$

Find the algebraic form of each and compare to the elements of $B$.

As for $3)$, note that $\ln(x)$ is only defined for $x > 0$. Hence, $\ln|x|$ is defined for $|x| > 0$. Knowing that this always happens except at $x=0$, the domain of $\ln|x|$ is $\mathbb R^*$. Hence $A = B$.

Comment: Great explanation. Now I understand.